# Why does the Email and Office fields only output system.object[]?

Tags: powershell

I can't understand why the Email and Office columns show system object instead of the respective values?  Can't figure out why the values from datafile02 aren't working but the values from datafile01 are.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$txt1 = "C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\New folder\datafile01.txt"
$txt2 = "C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\New folder\datafile02.txt"
$newtxt = "C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\New folder\new.txt"

#Import Data from TXT and add headers
$d1 = import-csv $txt1 -Header UID,HDATE,EMAIL,OFFICE -Delimiter `t | Select-Object -Property UID,EMAIL,HDATE,OFFICE 
$d2 = import-csv $txt2 -Header UID2, EMAIL, OFFICE -Delimiter `t | Select-Object -Property EMAIL, OFFICE

#Create new Table and Columns
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable "Employee Table"
$newcol = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn UID; $table.columns.add($newcol)
$newcol = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn EMAIL; $table.columns.add($newcol)
$newcol = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn HDATE; $table.columns.add($newcol)
$newcol = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn OFFICE; $table.columns.add($newcol)

 # Add a DataTable row
 $row = $table.NewRow()
 $row.UID= ($d1.UID)
 $row.EMAIL= ($d2.email)
 $row.HDATE= ($d1.HDATE)
 $row.OFFICE= ($d2.OFFICE)
 $table.Rows.Add($row)
 
 #Grab data from TXT
 $d1 | ForEach-Object {
     $row = $table.NewRow()
     $row.UID= ($_.UID)
     $row.EMAIL= ($d2.EMAIL)
     $row.HDATE= ($_.HDATE)
     $row.OFFICE= ($d2.OFFICE)
     $table.Rows.Add($row)
     } 

# Get the data out
 $table
```

Here is the output I'm getting from the code above.

```
UID             EMAIL           HDATE           OFFICE         
---             -----           -----           ------         
System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[]
25328           System.Object[] 5/31/2023       System.Object[]
57467           System.Object[] 9/14/2023       System.Object[]
55373           System.Object[] 1/21/2023       System.Object[]
41186           System.Object[] 6/15/2023       System.Object[]
60961           System.Object[] 3/14/2023       System.Object[]
```

Datafile01

```
25328   5/31/2023
57467   9/14/2023
55373   1/21/2023
41186   6/15/2023
60961   3/14/2023
```

Datafile02

```
25328   bdbrown@att.net Memphis
57467   boser@verizon.net   Portland
55373   tfinniga@optonline.net  Kansas City
68730   meinkej@sbcglobal.net   Huntington
41186   tubajon@outlook.com Santa Ana
60961   dwheeler@contoso.com    Detriot
```

The following code block worked!

```
Set-StrictMode -Version latest
$txt1 = "C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\New folder\datafile01.txt"
$txt2 = "C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\New folder\datafile02.txt"


#Import Data from TXT and add headers
$d1 = import-csv $txt1  -Delimiter `t -Header UID, SDate

$d2 = import-csv $txt2 -Delimiter `t -header UID, EMAIL, OFFICe

$d1 | ForEach-Object {
     $DataMatch = $d2 | Where-Object -Property UID -eq $_.UID
     [PSCustomObject]@{
        UID    = $_.UID
        Date   = $_.SDate
        Email  = $DataMatch.Email
        OFFICE = $DataMatch.OFFICE
    }

     }
```

Comment: `$d2.OFFICE` and `$d2.EMAIL` are arrays - not single elements!! ;-)

Comment: damn that was quick and I really appreciate your response but I don't understand what that means lol. What do I need to do then because they are arrays? Or how can I break them up into single elements? Or what's making them an array that isn't happening with the other 2 fields? Sorry I am new to this shit lol.

Comment: Thank you friend, just fixed it, how is it now?

Comment: You'll need to merge both CSVs on that ID column first then create your DataTable, it's not clear why one of the CSVs has `alex` as column name??

Comment: Ignore that, it was me just entering another field of data as a test.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can merge both on that one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$DataFile1 = Import-Csv .\DataFile1.txt -Delimiter "`t" -Header UID, Date
$DataFile2 = Import-Csv .\DataFile2.txt -Delimiter "`t" -Header UID, EMAIL, OFFICE

$DataFile1 |
ForEach-Object {
    $DataMatch = $DataFile2 | Where-Object -Property UID -EQ $_.UID
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        UID    = $_.UID
        Date   = $_.Date
        Email  = $DataMatch.Email
        OFFICE = $DataMatch.OFFICE
    }
}
```

You have to select the desired matching data row inside the loop.

Comment: TY.

When I enter this, I get the following error.

Where-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Property'. Specified method is not supported.

Guessing I need to convert it to a string. But can't figure out how or where to convert each field in the array to a string and then call them in a loop.

Comment: Oh you know what, I'm using import-csv but the data files are actually tab delimited text files. I did this so that could have fields, but maybe I should use something like get-content instead?

Comment: If your data file contains valid tab delimited plain text data you can use and you should use `Import-Csv`.

Comment: ... and you made a mistake inside the loop ... it should be `$d2 | ` instead of `$txt2 | `

Comment: TY I fixed the mistake, but to no avail.

and to answer your question. Both files contain the UID column but we only need one. I try and use select object to filter UID out of the 2nd text file because its not needed. Still running into an issue because of datatypes not being a string.

Comment: That wasn't my point. The parameter `-Header` and its values should reflect what's in your CSV input files. And you don't ned the `Select-Object` at all. It does not make any sense at this point. Just omit it.

Comment: I removed the select-object. Please keep in mind that the data files are tab delimited text files with no headers. I was using the -header property to include headers in the output but that was before I learned about building tables or custom objects, which I believe is where the proper place to build column headers in output is?

But that still leaves me stuck with this dam thing being an object and not a string.

Comment: You don't listen. It is right to use `Import-Csv` with the parameter `-Header` for your input files if they have tab delimited plain text data in them. But the values you provide for the parameter `-Header` have to reflect what's in your files. The value count should be the same like the columns in you CSV file.